# Ember action on='change' event

Tags: javascript, forms, ember.js, action, ember-cli

I have this ember action helper (which is just for experimenting)

```
{{input type='number' action='calculateMph' on='change'}} mph = {{controller.mph}} km/h
```

If I remove the `on='change'` it works fine when I press enter. But with `on='change'` it simply doesn't work at all. And the debugger isn't giving me anyting.

Am I doing something wrong? I want the action to run as you type into the input field and update the value live.

Here's my controller if it's any help.

```
var HomeController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  mph: null,

  actions: {
    calculateMph: function(parameter) {
      var result = parameter * 1.60934
      this.set('mph', result);
    }
  }
});
```

Note that I'm using ember CLI

Comment: what do you mean by on `change`? You might be looking for on `input` I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

controller.mph should be a property of the variable binded to the input:

```
{{input value=userNumber}}
```

So in this example a property of userNumber. There would be no action, but the controller.mph function would calculate the mph and return it. That way it will calculate every time the "userNumber" changes.

In general ember apps work best when they are using properties and not on-event actions if possible - pull, not push.